# Warning when running pnpm

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm

I get this warning anytime I run something like `pnpm i` any idea what might be causing this I know I'm going to have to set a config value I just can't figure out which one and what I need to set it to. Error is below.

```
 WARN Load npm builtin configs failed, you can use "pnpm config ls" to show builtin configs. And then use "pnpm config --global set <key> <value>" to migrate configs from builtin to global.
```

`pnpm config ls` shows the following:

```
❯ pnpm config ls
; "builtin" config from /Users/tsc/.local/opt/brew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc

prefix = "/Users/tsc/.local/opt/brew" 

; node bin location = /Users/tsc/.local/opt/brew/Cellar/node/18.11.0/bin/node
; node version = v18.11.0
; npm local prefix = /Users/tsc/Developer/learning/typescript-course
; npm version = 8.19.2
; cwd = /Users/tsc/Developer/learning/typescript-course
; HOME = /Users/tsc
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

Comment: what does `pnpm config ls` reveal?

Comment: @MattPengelly added to original question.

Comment: I don't have an answer now. It is a new warning that was added to solve an issue with settings. Track this issue: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5518

Comment: That is my issue, haha so no worries. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

zkochan pushed a commit recently -> "fix: downgrade `@pnpm/npm-conf` to remove annoying builtin warning (#5521)"

upgrade to `pnpm 7.13.6`